# Php curl for PayPal adaptive payments preaproval key

Tags: php, curl, paypal

New to PHP, trying to add PayPal's adaptive payment option to a site I am building.

I need to format this following code found at [PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) into php curl :

```
curl -s --insecure
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username"
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password"
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature"
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV"
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: app_id"
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval  -d
"cancelUrl=http://your_cancel_url
&currencyCode=USD
&endingDate=2009-12-13T08%3A00%3A00.000Z
&maxAmountPerPayment=200.00
&maxNumberOfPayments=30
&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=1500.00
&pinType=NOT_REQUIRED
&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
&returnUrl=http://your_return_url
&startingDate=2009-07-13T07%3A00%3A00.000Z
&senderEmail=sender@domain
```

Came up with the following :

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    paypal_url = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval';
    paypal_header_options = array();
    paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username";
    paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password";
    paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature";
    paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV";
    paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV";
    paypal_header_options[] = "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: app_id";


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, paypal_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, paypal_header_options);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    paypal_response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

so my question is where does this go :

```
    "cancelUrl=http://your_cancel_url
    &currencyCode=USD
    &endingDate=2009-12-13T08%3A00%3A00.000Z
    &maxAmountPerPayment=200.00
    &maxNumberOfPayments=30
    &maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=1500.00
    &pinType=NOT_REQUIRED
    &requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
    &returnUrl=http://your_return_url
    &startingDate=2009-07-13T07%3A00%3A00.000Z
    &senderEmail=sender@domain
```

and what is `-d` ? I have searched but wasn't able to find and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push that data inside the post parameter fields as below:

```
$paypal_data_d = 'cancelUrl=...&senderEmail=sender@domain';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paypal_data_d);
```